# Spring boot always send error on localhost:8080

Tags: spring-boot, controller

I have UserRepository

```
    package registry;
    import Entity.User;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

UserController

```
package controller;

import Entity.User;
import exception.NoUserFoundException;
import exception.UserNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import registry.UserRepository;
import service.UserService;

import javax.xml.ws.Response;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"controller", "service","registry"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/user/getall")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getAllUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

ApplicationRunner

```
package Application;

import Entity.User;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import registry.UserRepository;
import service.UserService;
import service.UserServiceImpl;
import controller.UserController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRunner  {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }

}
```

The application runs fine.
When I type the url "localhost://8080" or "localhost://8080/user/getall" I have the following error message :

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 30 01:30:30 CEST 2021

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Anyhelp appreciated

Comment: `localhost://8080` isn't a valid URL, use `localhost:8080/` instead. However `localhost:8080` doesn't exists so you will get a 404. Also please remove the `@Repository` from the interface (it doesn't do anything) and remove the `@SpringBootApplication` from your controller.  Next your structure is wrong, your `ApplicationRunner` should be in a package that covers your other packages (so your other packages should be something like `Application.controller` and `Application.registry`.

Answer (score 0):

URL should be like HOST:PORT
Use URL : http://localhost:8080/user/getall

Answer (score 0):

Sorry It's a typo.
The url is http://localhost:8080/user/getall

The problem remains